# how to specify cell value according to its content in sum formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a column contains some texts as follow:

```
one
two
three
four
```

I want to sum the values this column cells according to their content, so I should check the content then return a value, as `if(cell = one) then 1`

so the sum result should be 1+2+3+4 = `10`
I tried to do a formula like `=SUM(IF(A1=apartment,1),...)` but its absolutely wrong.

how can I write this formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do:-

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A1:A10={"One","two","three","four"})*{1,2,3,4})
```

This builds up a 2d array where the rows correspond to your data and the columns correspond to the strings "one","two","three" and "four". The elements are set 'true' only where the data matches one of the four strings. Then this array is multiplied by the row of numbers 1,2,3 and 4. 'TRUE' counts as 1 in the multiplication and 'FALSE' counts as 0.

Comment: Thank you. I  like to think of myself as Gary's student's student.

Comment: Well said. I am thinking now that if you put the two answers together and did something like =SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF(A1:A10,{"one","two","three","four"})*{1,2,3,4}) it would be better still. I think I saw Scott Craner do something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Count the words and multiple by the associated values:

```
=COUNTIF(A:A,"one")+2*COUNTIF(A:A,"two")+3*COUNTIF(A:A,"three")+4*COUNTIF(A:A,"four")+5*COUNTIF(A:A,"five")
```

[image]

You can extend this formula by adding more terms if necessary, or use a *VLOOKUP()* table.